# I deleted my node modules and package lock.json and tried reinstalling them back using npm install but i keep getting this errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules, package.json

This is the update error
i updated the css-loader and i am getting new error

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: app@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: webpack@5.74.0
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   dev webpack@"^5.74.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@"^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0" from html-webpack-plugin@3.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/html-webpack-plug in
npm ERR!   html-webpack-plugin@"^3.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\OBIORA JUSTICE\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\OBIORA JUSTICE\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-26T09_37_37_869Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of `css-loader` specified in your dependencies works with Webpack 4, but you're also depending on Webpack 5.

Upgrade `css-loader` in your `package.json` to a newer version (e.g. 6.7.1, the current version), then try again.

Comment: i have updated it but still encountering the same error

Comment: The _very_ same error? With the _very_ same `css-loader@"^2.1.1"` in there? If so, then you didn't update it.

Comment: Sorry not the same error but a different error, i just edited my question, thats the updated error

Comment: @ObioraChukwuemekaJustice Well, the same fix stands, only this time it's `html-webpack-plugin` which is too old.